# How to implement a generic encoder?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, encoder

I want to implement a generic encoder because I have a small project on Spark 1.6 and when I migrate it to the spark 2.0 its giving me the warning and error 
of

```
Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
```

at many places hence I want to implement a generic encoder and put it in package object. I just want to know how can I implement a generic Encoder in spark 2.0 ?

Comment: It's just a trait http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developing custom encoders usually starts with composing existing encoders from [org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$) object.

Please note that many places in Spark check whether the encoder in use is an instance of [ExpressionEncoder](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/encoders/ExpressionEncoder.scala) (i.e. [SparkSession.createDataset](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@createDataset[T](data:Seq[T])(implicitevidence$4:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[T]):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T])) so you may want to review expression encoders as the base for custom development.